# Scala - JsonPath - Check if object property has an specific value

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

I have the following json object

```
{ 
"object1":{  
  "0":{  
     "prop1":"3",
     "prop2":1530741600000
  },
  "1":{  
     "prop1":"4",
     "prop2":1530741600000
  }      
}
}
```

I want to know if object1 has an element whose property prop1 is equals than 3.

I am trying `$.object1[@.prop1 == "4"]` or `$.object1[*[@.prop1 == "4"]]`but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you are nearly there, you just need to use a filter expression `[?(expression)]` and make sure you are looking in the right level of the json

```
$.object1.*[?(@.prop1 == "4")]
```

https://github.com/gatling/jsonpath